# How do I extend a UIToolbar across landscape orientation in iOS7?

Tags: xcode, ios7, orientation, landscape, uitoolbar

I have a UIToolbar set up in my view controller that has a width of 768, extending across portrait view as I desire. But when I rotate to landscape, the toolbar maintains the same width, instead of extending to 1024 pixels.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure this out. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for leaving that detail out.

Comment: Can you post your constrains?

Comment: The only constraint I have for the Toolbar is to pin it to the bottom of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Horizontal Space constrains as below:

[image]

Comment: It works, thanks! My bar is now pinned on either side. Much appreciated.